# Bijectivity of the map from $K^n \to \operatorname{Spm} K[X_1,...,X_n]$ and help needed in understanding this terminology

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, terminology

I am doing a 1st course in Algebraic Geometry and this question was asked in 1st assignment of the course.

> Let K be an algebraically closed field. Then show that the map $K^n \to \operatorname{Spm} K[X_1,...,X_n]$ , $a\mapsto m_a=\langle X_1- a_1,...,X_n-a_n\rangle$ is bijective. Moreover, for any ideal $A\in J(K[X_1,...,X_n])$, $a\in V_K(A)$ iff $A \subseteq M_A$.

Surjectivity of the map is clear. For injectivity, let $\langle X_1- a_1,...,X_n-a_n\rangle = \langle X_1 -b_1,...,X_n-b_n\rangle$, I have to prove that $(a_1,...,a_n)= (b_1,...,b_n)$.

$\langle X_1- a_1,...,X_n-a_n\rangle = \langle X_1 -b_1,...,X_n-b_n\rangle$ implies that there exists ${k_i}'s
, {k'}_i's \in K$ such that $k_1 (x_1 -a_1) +...+ k_n (x_n -a_n)={k'}_1( x_1-b_1) +... + {k'}_n (x_n-b_n)$ which implies that $(k_1 -{k'}_1)x_1 +...+(k_n -{k'}_n) x_n= a_1 k_1+ ...+a_n k_n - b_1 {k'}_1  -... - {k'}_n b_n$. But I am not able to move foreward from now, ie how to prove that $(a_1,...,a_n)= (b_1,...,b_n)$. Please guide.

For the other question (after moreover), I could not attempt anything because I don't know what exactly is meant by $J(K[X_1,...,X_n])$. I think it might be Jacobson Radical of $ K[X_1,...,X_n]$ but I am not sure. Can you please confirm?

Comment: The existence of $k$'s such that the equation holds does not guarantee the conclusion. You can take all $k$'s to be $0$. You may have meant a forall instead of an exists on one of the sets of $k$'s.

Comment: Please use \langle and \rangle instead of < and >, they look much better. I've made a couple other MathJax improvements, please take a look at your post and keep these in mind for the future.

Comment: The ideal $\langle X_{1} - a_{1}, \ldots, X_{n}-a_{n}\rangle$ is precisely the kernel of the evaluation morphism $K[X_{1}, \ldots, X_{n}] \to K$ sending $X_{i}$ to $a_{i}$. (If you haven't proved this/seen a proof of it, you should convince yourself of this.) In particular, if $\langle X_{1} - a_{1}, \ldots, X_{n}-a_{n}\rangle = \langle X_{1} - b_{1}, \ldots, X_{n}-b_{n}\rangle$, then $X_{i}-b_{i}$ vanishes when we evaluate at $(a_{1}, \ldots, a_{n})$, which implies $a_{i}-b_{i} = 0$, i.e. $a_{i} = b_{i}$.

Comment: @AlexWertheim Can you please help with other part also?

Comment: @AlexWertheim Can you please help if you have some time to spare?